# How do I put Dropdown and image on the same line

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a website for a fake company and im struggling with putting an image and a dropdown on the same line

This is what I tried :

```
<body> 
      <img src="Kharabora Coding-1 (1).png" height="150px" class="img">  
        <form style="background-color: #ffffff">  
        <div class="dropdown" style="padding-left: 1300px;">
            <button class="dropbtn"><a href="#" class="a-a">LATEST WORK</a></button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="dropdown3" style="padding-left: 75px;">
            <button class="dropbtn3"><a href="#" class="a-2">WHAT WE DO</a></button>
            <div class="dropdown-content3">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="dropdown2" style="padding-left: 75px;">
            <button class="dropbtn2"><a href="#" class="a-1">ABOUT</a></button>
            <div class="dropdown-content2">
            </div>
          </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
         </body>
```

and it ended up looking like this : [image]

Please help

Answer (score 0):

div tags are by default displayed as a block. you have to either modify their display as inline, or use a tag that has display as inline by default.

learn more about it here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp

Answer (score 0):

just use flex

```css
div{display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
}
*{
border:solid 1px black;
margin:5px;}

html{border:none;}
```

```html
<div>
<img src='https://via.placeholder.com/50'>
<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<img src='https://via.placeholder.com/50'>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but it didn't work

Comment: what didn't work?

Comment: using flex didn't work

Comment: it seems to wok here, what's the problem?  Show your complete code

Answer (score 0):

To make things appear on the same line, you can use **display: flex** or **display: grid**.

[learn more about grid](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp)

[learn more about flex](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.php)

```css
.row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.links {
    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x75" class="img">
    <div class="links">
        <a href="#">LATEST WORK</a>
        <a href="#">WHAT WE DO</a>
        <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
    </div>
</div>
```